# Locate error in URLMappings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7.5

I am facing this problem when I host my application on a websever. It's running nicly on the local server. I host the application on Godaddy.

Here is the link where I am getting the error: `http://crestlogix.com/test`

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 9:      <system.web>
Line 10:       <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
Line 11:       <urlMappings enabled="true">
Line 12:         <add url="~/college-management-software" mappedUrl="~/college_management_software.aspx"/>
Line 13:         <add url="~/hospital-management-software" mappedUrl="~/hospital_management_software.aspx"/>
```

What can I do to resolve the error?